# Is O365 (SharePoint Online) Visitor Group able to browse the groups and members?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

i have a general question on browsing groups and members in O365. For example my user is in the Visitors Group. Would he be able to read alle the Web or even SiteCollections SharePoint Groups and list its members via JSOM?

Comment: Not if access is disabled in the Group Settings page

Comment: And if enabled, then irrespective of the permission/group membership of the current user it would be possible?

Comment: If you tell SP, users can browse groups then they can browse groups.. UI, JSOM, no difference in access-rights